# error occur during git installation on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, installation, sudo, apt

When I attempt to install git on Ubuntu 20.04,I get an error. I used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and it generated an **error:**

```
dpkg: warning: old mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[As shown here](https://askubuntu.com/a/380701/5470), that means the config.dat file is used by another process, that you need to kill.

```
sudo fuser -v -k /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

That would kill directly said other process.

Then you can try again your install command.